# I want to create array of key value pair of an object see in the exam

Tags: typescript, types

I need to configure some table and I need this type
to create object with the key and the value of each keys

```js
 type KeyValuePair<T> = {/** ... */};
let userKeyValuePair :KeyValuePair<{id:number,userName:string}>;
 // => {key:'id',value: number} or {key: 'userName', value: string}

userKeyValuePair = {key: 'id' /** with autocomplete */ , value: 'string'}; // will be cause error
userKeyValuePair = {key: 'id' ,value: 687 /** any number */}; // will work fine
```

Comment: Please include your full `KeyValuePair` type.

Comment: It is important to know how the generic type `T` is used inside the `KeyValuePair`, it could give a hint to what causes the error. Could you also add the error displayed by the first assignation of `userKeyValuePair`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
type KeyValuePair<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: { key: K, value: T[K] }
}[keyof T];
```

This is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that iterates over each key and produces the desired corresponding object type, like `{a: string, b: number}` will first become `{a: {key: "a", value: string}, b: {key: "b", value: number}}`.  We then immediately [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with its keys to get a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of its property types.  So then `{a: string, b: number}` becomes `{key: "a", value: string} | {key: "b", value: number}`.

Observe:

```
type Show = KeyValuePair<{ id: number, userName: string }>;
/* type Show = {
    key: "id";
    value: number;
} | {
    key: "userName";
    value: string;
} */
```

And we can try it on your example:

```
let userKeyValuePair: KeyValuePair<{ id: number, userName: string }>;

userKeyValuePair = { key: 'id' /** with autocomplete */, value: 'string' }; // error
userKeyValuePair = { key: 'id', value: 687 /** any number */ }; // okay
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIDUCGAbArhACkglgJwB4AVAPigF4oBvAWACgooBtGKHAOygGt4B7AMyhEAugFoA-AC5q3eNJgAaKADdUGaURbCoAX3o6mPEAKHCA3PXqhIUAMoALXgHcKseMnRZchKmwAm0uxoALYARhB4SmgAzhEAckjBENLRwHgcAOa6JBZ0APQAVFDW0A7OrrQMjLIg0gBEOH51udUqaslQQWERuTpQAD7U9K1G9THxiRDNw9Wqnilpmb1QBXmWdPQoEMBQ43hwiO3Y+PLuR94Evo2BIeGRu7F4CUkL6exZOjnrewceGMd4Co1aQAckaIKghSKThwwHsUCQaGAvAAxrxgmAtsBoKslHN1FAQak3hkITozJC8lAInheHh6D8zp4AUDRoTwXj2tIAGwADgA7JCCkUkOwQJ1bhEVlTyZSoLwuEgQEA)

Comment: Thanks
I get the result after a while but yours much cleaner thanks

Comment: @פניקסמפתחים Please consider accepting and/or upvoting this answer if it meets your needs.